# How to implement an interface member that has no name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface like this (which is valid TypeScript)

```
interface IPerson {
    (name: string, age: number): IPerson,
    getSomething(): string
}
```

Which I am trying to implement in a class:

```
class Person implements IPerson {
    constructor(private something: string) {

    }

    getSomething(): string {
        return this.something;
    } 
}
```

How do I implement the `(name: string, age: number): IPerson` member?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a static named method? At least, that would solve your problem.

Comment: No problem here. Just got curious seeing some typescript definition files with interface declarations like these. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface you posted describes a function with a specific signature which also has an additional method called `getSomething`.
In the docs that is described as [Hybrid Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types).

I don't think that there's an way to create a class that implements it, you basically just need to have a factory function which creates instances which implement this interface:

```
function createPerson(name: string, age: number): IPerson {
    let person = function(newName: string, newAge: number) {
        return createPerson(newName, newAge);
    } as IPerson;
    person.getSomething = function () {
        return `${ name }: ${ age }`;
    }

    return person;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IPerson%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%3A%20IPerson%2C%0A%20%20%20%20getSomething()%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20createPerson(name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%3A%20IPerson%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20person%20%3D%20function(newName%3A%20string%2C%20newAge%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20createPerson(newName%2C%20newAge)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20as%20IPerson%3B%0A%20%20%20%20person.getSomething%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60%24%7B%20name%20%7D%3A%20%24%7B%20age%20%7D%60%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20person%3B%0A%7D))

It's a weird definition though.

Answer (score 1):

That's a function type. You should implement this way...

```js
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

let mySearch: SearchFunc;
mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
    let result = source.search(subString);
    return result > -1;
}
```

I do not know if it's possible that a class implements this directly.

Check typescript hand book Function Types http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

Hm, perhaps this way?

```
var person = ((): IPerson => {
    var x: any = function (name: string, age: number): IPerson {
                      return this;
                 }
    x.getName = function () {
                      return "NAME";
                 }
    return x;
    }
);
```

.... JS ....

```
var person = (function () {
    var x = function (name, age) {
        return this;
    };
    x.getName = function () {
        return "NAME";
    };
    return x;
});
```